# is it possible to use enum type of one schema in another schema in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, enums, schema

I have a problem here about postgresql. I have defined an enum type `abc` in schema `X`. Now I want to create a table having a column with datatype `abc` in schema `Y`. Is it possible to do such a thing? If yes how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to qualify the schema, when defining the data type:

```
create table y.other_table
(
   some_enum   x.abc
);
```